# Ubuntu Ethernet Duplex setting fault

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet

I am trying to connect my Ubuntu 18.0.4 hardware to a managed switch that has the duplex set to Full and speed set to 100. The Switch cannot be configured to Auto mode because it is customer requirement since Auto mode will mask/hide wiring problems.

Here is a brief of the situation:

https://linoxide.com/how-to-check-ethernet-duplex-mode/

When we force Ubuntu to use 100/Full with the ethtool it does not work. It works when we force it to 10/Full.

Many different variations of operating systems where tested. aarm64 built Ubuntu variants (Both 18.04 and the modern 20.04.) And after trying both of those I also tried the traditional architecture of x64 ubuntu (Both 18.04 and 20.04) and all variants tested exhibited the exact same issues. The only way to get full duplex is to let the the ports auto negotiate. Otherwise it falls back to half.

We tried everything described in the article above but no success with 100/Full. I am out of ideas so please can anyone shed some light and help me?

I need to find a way to force Ubuntu to connect the ethernet at 100/Full without auto mode.

Thanks,